# Can I take a flight that departs after midnight of the day my Schengen visa expires?

Tags: schengen, visa-expiration

I have short term german visa for three days.

I don't have a flight in my budget on the 3rd day night so I want to know if I can finish my immigration on the 3rd day night and take up the flight next day morning.

Do the airline companies and immigration allow such things.

Comment: If it is at all possible, it would also depend on the airport (whether it's opened at night and there is some area where you could wait airside). Specifically, Tegel in Berlin definitely isn't like that.

Comment: What airport would you fly from?

Answer (score 8):

You have to officially depart Germany before midnight on the day your visa expires. After you cross the line at passport control you are no longer "in" Germany as far as immigration is concerned.

However, unless your departure flight is shortly after midnight you won't get past security. The cutoff time is dependent on the airport but "8am the next day" will definitely be out of the question.

You need to either get a flight before your visa expires or talk to immigration about it. Preferably well before midnight on day 3.