# Will I have exit issues at Moscow airport leaving 1 hour after my visa expires?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, russia, borders, dme

I am travelling to Moscow. My visa is stamped from 08 July to 15 July. My return flight is on 16 July at 1 am from Domodedovo Airport.
Will it be okay for me to travel?

Comment: [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44625/52465) is about Germany, not Russia, and says it's OK.

Answer (score 4):

If you clear passport control before midnight, it's fine. The Moment you're stamped out, you've officially departed Russia.

Comment: Source? The border guards do look at your boarding pass, so they'll know you're not leaving until after midnight.

Comment: @AlexanderDunlap Still, clearing the border is what counts as exiting. The only time it's about the flight time is when there's no exit border control (like in the US)

Comment: I believe that @AlexanderDunlap's point is that the Russian officers might decline to give the traveler a normal departure stamp when they see that the flight departs after the visa expires. You are probably correct that if the traveler can get a departure stamp before midnight that all will be well, but I'm not convinced that this will happen, and your answer offers no evidence in support of either assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the rules about international flights are saying that you must check-in at least 1 hour before going to the gate. Given that, combined with your departure time (1 A.M.), you should be fine, as you'll go through the passport control on the previous day, with a valid visa.

[Every gate](http://www.domodedovo.ru/passengers/map/) in Domodedovo has the border control, and a waiting zone after that, and usually you can check-in 3 hours before the flight. So, you should just pass the border checks before and enjoy your trip.